# Fixed scroll position when scroll height changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am developing a chatroom with pagination and i am loading old messages when scroll heigth equals to 0, but the thing is when scroll height expanded scroll position still 0, it's not like facebook, slack and the other apps chatroom.
I want to make stabil position when scroll height expanded.
I try to change scroll height but it's working smoothly and i didn't expect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get new chat element by id and scroll to that element.

```
document.scrollTop = document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
```

Here is an example:

```js
let index = 0;
        function addBox() {
            document.body.innerHTML += `<div class="box" id='box${index}'></div>`;
            document.scrollTop = document.getElementById(`box${index}`).scrollIntoView();
        }
```

```css
* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .box {
            height: 200px;
            background-color: blueviolet;
        }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button onclick="addBox()">Click here to add</button>
```

Comment: how can i do this with react ?
let say my scroll expanding with data array on useState, how can i handle this situation.
thanks for helping ^_^

Comment: You can use it like when your array size increase use quearyselectorAll(.card) and last choose element and scrollTotop()

Comment: If you have any problem comment again.